# Acceptability of gentile fasting

Tags: gentiles, fast-days, islam

Something was brought up in a lecture by Rabbi Mizrachi (I'm not sure which video) where he says that Muslims try to follow everything Jews do--and they try to "one up" so to speak. The three daily prayers become five to imitate praying during Yom Kippur (shachrit, minchah, mussaf, arvit nehila), among other things.

This got me thinking in the point of fasting. Muslims fast during Ramadan for 28 days. However, this is awfully like creating a holy day period, which I would think goes against the Ramba"m in not gentiles not making a holy day[s] for themselves. Being that it is a religious period that adds to the sheva mitzvot (Muslims must fast and is completely obligatory), seems like it would be forbidden since they are creating a mitzvah to fast, although I am not sure.

However, lets say there is a Muslim who fasts extra days throughout the year. Is this considered in the same respect as creating a mitzvah or, alternatively, is he performing a mitzvah?

Comment: It would appear that Rb Mizrahi's statement is *keneged* the *halacha* that one should always seek to promote peaceable relationships with non-Jewish people.

Comment: @pcoz IIRC After stating this, he said something along the lines of "look how far we fallen: the Israeli Army only killed x (hamas operative) when they could find him, at 4:30AM because he went to the mosque to pray. How many of us are willing to die just to pray that early... [while being] targeted, instead I hear, 'Rabbi, maybe B"H I'll be here tomorrow at 10' ". He was speaking rather highly of their dedication, and how they are doing this because they love Hashem, and they were never given the level of miracles am Israel had. The antagonistic nature is my own summarizing.

Comment: Apologies for the criticism. Historically, mainstream orthodox rabbanim did not refer to other religions to learn lessons in Judaism. So for example, it seems somewhat objectionable to motivate me to go to shul on time for *shacharis* because that it what a murderer did.

Comment: Doesn't the Rambam only forbid non-Jews to make days of rest? They can make fast days if they want to.

Comment: Yonah HaNavi would appear to have a positive view of gentile fasting

Comment: @JoshK  My question is more geared towards the idea of "what if Yonah hadn't come," I guess.